# Is this implementation bad programming?

Tags: c#, bubble-sort

I made the algorithm below for bubblesort exercise at school.

```
//Bubble Sort (My code)
static void _BubbleSort(int[] a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.Length - 1 - i; j++)
        {
            if (a[j] > a[j + 1])
            {
                swap(a, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I check the internet I see different algorithm below. 
The algorithm I found in internet uses different "for" loop as follows. Mine is nested for loops but the code below is not nested.

```
public void BubbleSort(int[] b)
{
    for (int pass = 1; pass < b.Length; pass++) // passes

        for (int i = 0; i < b.Length - 1; i++) // one pass

            if (b[i] > b[i + 1]) // one comparison
                Swap(b, i); // one swap
}
```

What I want to ask is my code is an example of bad programming or not? or my brain is working different than you computer science guys? I am arts student by the way if you wonder.

Comment: With bubblesort, you do the second loop until there are no more swaps then you stop.  Do not carry on until the length of the array.

Comment: This will be mostly opinionated answers

Comment: @JensKloster This is not about cleaning up code, this is about comparing two implementations. This is also not about opinions. This does not belong at Code Review.

Comment: "but the code below is not nested"?

Comment: Can you make nested code without using brackets ? I learned something new

Comment: Yes you can. The nested code will only include *one line*. That's why you should use curly brackets.

Comment: @Lyrk, yep, if you only have one statement after the `for`, `if` etc, then the braces can be omitted. It's generally considered good practice not to though as it all too easily leads to problems.

Comment: @Lyrk You can and you shouldn't do it. https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/ is the best example.

Comment: @chillworld, ah I knew there was a real-world case that caused "always use braces" to change from opinion to fact. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Nitpick: It is not "one line". It is one statement :p

Comment: @SriramSakthivel You're killing me ;P It's 15:45, hard times :X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I want to ask is my code is an example of bad programming or not?

Your code *almost* is identical. There is a difference in that you are (correctly) using curly brackets to explicitly state code blocks, while the other example isn't. One problem is your *loop bounds check*.

@Sriram also pointed to the fact that your loop uses `a.Length - 1 - i` while the latter simply checks for `b.Length - 1`, which isn't actually necessary on your part and would cause the loop to prematurely end. Use the latter approach from the second example.

Other than the fact you shouldn't use `_` at the beginning of your method (this is simply a naming convertion), your algorithm is identical.

Comment: Not really. Loop conditions are different.

Comment: @Sriram Not really. He's using `int i = 0; a.Length - 1` which is merely identical.

Comment: You're overlooking it dude.  check this one `j < a.Length - 1 - i`

Comment: 2nd for loop condition is different.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Damn. Yes, I overlooked. Fixed my answer.

Comment: @bviale, his implementation is also an example of bad programming because he's created (been asked to create) a bubble sort. It's possible to be too pedantic at times though...

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, "It's possible to be too pedantic at times though" ;)